# Does this code rightly demonstrates Polymorphism ? (JAVA)

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

I have written a small program to practice and demonstrate polymorphism in Java, So please take a look and let me know if the idea is properly implemented or not.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        porche porche_car = new porche("Porche 9/11",8,"black");

        porche_car.startEngine(true);
        porche_car.accelerate(250);
        porche_car.brake(true);


        Ford ford_car = new Ford("Ford SUV",4,"blue");

        ford_car.startEngine(true);
        ford_car.accelerate(200);
        ford_car.brake(false);
    }
}

public class Car {

    private boolean engine;
    private String name;
    private int cylinders;
    private int wheels;

    public Car(String name, int cylinders)
    {
        this.engine = true;
        this.name = name;
        this.cylinders = cylinders;
        this.wheels = 4;
    }

    public void startEngine(boolean start)
    {
        if(start)
        {
            System.out.println(getName()+"Class.Engine Started.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(getName()+" Class.Engine Stopped.");
        }
    }

    public void accelerate(int acceleration)
    {
            System.out.println(getName()+" class.Accelerating car at " + acceleration + " Km/h");

    }
    public void brake(boolean applybrake)
    {
        if (applybrake)
        {
            System.out.println(getName()+" class called.Brakes applied.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(getName()+" class, brakes released.");
        }
    }

    public boolean isEngine() {
        return engine;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getCylinders() {
        return cylinders;
    }

    public int getWheels() {
        return wheels;
    }
}

public class porche extends Car{
    private String color;
    private int doors;

    public porche(String name, int cylinders, String color) {
        super(name, cylinders);
        this.color = color;
        this.doors = 2;
    }

    @Override
    public void startEngine(boolean start) {
        super.startEngine(start);
    }

    @Override
    public void accelerate(int acceleration) {
        super.accelerate(acceleration);
    }

    @Override
    public void brake(boolean applybrake) {
        super.brake(applybrake);
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public int getDoors() {
        return doors;
    }
}

public class Ford extends Car{
    private String color;
    private int doors;

    public Ford(String name, int cylinders, String color) {
        super(name, cylinders);
        this.color = color;
        this.doors = 2;
    }

    @Override
    public void startEngine(boolean start) {
        super.startEngine(start);
    }

    @Override
    public void accelerate(int acceleration) {
        super.accelerate(acceleration);
    }

    @Override
    public void brake(boolean applybrake) {
        super.brake(applybrake);
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public int getDoors() {
        return doors;
    }
}
```

Note : An overview, I created a base class Car and extended to create 2 more classes(Porche and Ford) and I overided the methods in Car class to add functionality of base Car class to its subclasses.(in order to implement Polymorphism.) Is the implementation acceptable ?

**UPDATE** Actually the code I posted was a challenge, I am doing a course from udemy (java master class). After I completed my challenge I looked at what was the solution given there.In that solution, approach similar to mine was used, code from that solution is given below:

```
class Car {
private boolean engine;
private int cylinders;
private String name;
private int wheels;

public Car(int cylinders, String name) {
    this.cylinders = cylinders;
    this.name = name;
    this.wheels = 4;
    this.engine = true;
}

public int getCylinders() {
    return cylinders;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String startEngine() {
    return "Car -> startEngine()";
}

public String accelerate() {
    return "Car -> accelerate()";
}

public String brake() {
    return "Car -> brake()";
}
```

class Mitsubishi extends Car {

```
public Mitsubishi(int cylinders, String name) {
    super(cylinders, name);
}

@Override
public String startEngine() {
    return "Mitsubishi -> startEngine()";
}

@Override
public String accelerate() {
    return "Mitsubishi -> accelerate()";
}

@Override
public String brake() {
    return "Mitsubishi -> brake()";
}
```

class Holden extends Car {

```
public Holden(int cylinders, String name) {
    super(cylinders, name);
}

@Override
public String startEngine() {
    return getClass().getSimpleName() +  " -> startEngine()";
}

@Override
public String accelerate() {
    return getClass().getSimpleName() +  " -> accelerate()";
}

@Override
public String brake() {
    return getClass().getSimpleName() +  " -> brake()";
}
```

class Ford extends Car {

```
public Ford(int cylinders, String name) {
    super(cylinders, name);
}

@Override
public String startEngine() {
    return "Ford -> startEngine()";
}

@Override
public String accelerate() {
    return "Ford -> accelerate()";
}

@Override
public String brake() {
    return "Ford -> brake()";
}
```

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // We are going to go back to the car analogy.
    // Create a base class called Car
    // It should have a few fields that would be appropriate for a generice car calss.
    // engine, cylinders, wheels, etc.
    // Constructor should initialize cylinders (number of) and name, and set wheels to 4
    // and engine to true. Cylinders and names would be passed parameters.
    //
    // Create appropriate getters
    //
    // Create some methods like startEngine, accelerate, and brake
    //
    // show a message for each in the base class
    // Now create 3 sub classes for your favorite vehicles.
    // Override the appropriate methods to demonstrate polymorphism in use.
    // put all classes in the one java file (this one).

    Car car = new Car(8, "Base car");
    System.out.println(car.startEngine());
    System.out.println(car.accelerate());
    System.out.println(car.brake());

    Mitsubishi mitsubishi = new Mitsubishi(6, "Outlander VRX 4WD");
    System.out.println(mitsubishi.startEngine());
    System.out.println(mitsubishi.accelerate());
    System.out.println(mitsubishi.brake());

    Ford ford = new Ford(6, "Ford Falcon");
    System.out.println(ford.startEngine());
    System.out.println(ford.accelerate());
    System.out.println(ford.brake());

    Holden holden = new Holden(6, "Holden Commodore");
    System.out.println(holden.startEngine());
    System.out.println(holden.accelerate());
    System.out.println(holden.brake());
}
```

Comment: No need to override methods if you just call the base class method.

Comment: Not really. You override the methods for nothing, since all they do is call the superclass implementation. Polymorphism would be better illustrated if you had two variables of type Car, and if calling the same method on the two variables did something *different*, because the actual concrete class is different, and both classes override the method to do something different.

Comment: I understand, my goal was to just show the idea of dynamic polymorphism even though I didnt remove or modify functionality when overriding methods from superclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to demonstrate example of polymorphism would be to write a method that accepts argument of base class and reuse that method by passing objects of child class(es).

For example :-

```
     public class Test{

     public static void main(String[] args){

         Car c = new Car();
        checkCar(c);
        c = new Ferrari();
        checkCar(c);
        c = new Honda();
        checkCar(c);

     }




    public static void checkCar(Car c){

        c.start();
    }
  }

 class Car{

    public void start(){
        System.out.println("Car Starts");
    }

 };

 class Ferrari extends Car{
    public void start(){
        System.out.println("Ferrari Starts");
    }
 };

 class Honda extends Car{
    public void start(){
        System.out.println("Honda Starts");
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your example is to simple to use polymorphism. You've invoked methods from base class as was mentioned in comments above. You don't need to override this methods to use them in derived classes.

Secondly, you used derived classes as a type of variables in main function so you can't notice how polymorphism works. You should use base class Car instead.

```
Car porche_car = new Porche("Porche 9/11",8,"black");
porche_car.startEngine(true); // uses method from Porsche class if overriden
```

Comment: What is the reason to use Car as base class ?

Comment: @calculusnoob Because that's what polymorphism is all about: when you have a car, invoking a polmorphic method will call the Porsche method if the actual type of the car is a Porsche, and will invoke the Ford method if the actual type of the car is Ford, without any need fo you to know what the concrete type is.

Comment: Take a look at my post again, I gave some more information.